# Alternative location for motorcycle ignition coils?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, ignition

I recently replaced the ignition coils on my 81 Suzuki 450. The aftermarket coils are just large enough that the tank won't seat right,  even after adjusting the bracket.

Would there be any issue in mounting the coils to a different spot on the frame?  I was thinking the vertical tubes between the tank and the handlebar.... I have enough slack to do this without rewiring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A Good Ground

All the coils on that bike want are a good ground.

If you can find a good spot on the frame to mount them that isn't in the way you are good.  Feel free to weld a couple of tabs onto a random convenient spot anywhere on the good iron from that you can.

Best of luck.